# Using Router Class inside function

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am writing some route helper functions for my angular2 app.. is it possible to inject Router class in normal function.... instead of injecting it in the constructor of class.

I am trying to do something like this

```ts
 import {Router} from "angular2/router";
    export function show404()
    {
        var _location=new Location();
        var _router=new Router(.......);
        this._location.replaceState('/');
        this._router.navigateByUrl('/404/');

    }
```

Is it possible to use Router class like this, If it is possible then how can I?

Answer (score 1):

Angular DI only injects into constructors and only for instances it creates itself.

What you can do though is to use the injector and request the router from the injector.

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
]).then((appRef: ComponentRef) => {
  console.log("booting")
    appInjector(appRef.injector);
});

...

let router = appInjector.get(Router);
```

For a full working example see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zVGnd8noWfbxwfuEVr9x?p=preview) from this discussion https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112.